# running rails project with nginx gives 403 forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have rails application want to deploy on digitalocean but when running the application with nginx it only sees what is in public folder but the home gives 403 forbidden
Any suggestions ??

Comment: Have you set up basic auth or something?  This seems related to that.

Comment: Is nginx running as some user (www-user, or alike), that cannot see the public folder? And how is your site setup? Reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this carefully and deployment should be working fine

https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04

Choose which ubuntu version you're using on your droplet